# Should I use MVVM or just a ContentControl for loading Screens?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, mvvm-light

I am developing an Application with the following layout, 
I have no knowledge of MVVM and I'm on a tight timeline.
The Red area on the right is a ContentControl.
The area on the left will be a sidebar for Navigation

[image]

My question is

1. should I follow this aproach
   http://channs.blogspot.com/2010/09/wpf-navigation.html OR
2. should I use MVVM light / Prism  OR
3. should I use WPF pages?

I am currently inclined to option 1. Are there any pros and cons to it?
Which option would you recommend ?
My application will always have only one developer i.e.  Me and it will contain about 30 screens.

Comment: Back in 2010, I had the opportunity to meet Mr Billy Hollis, and had a small chat about his Stafflynx application, he used option 1 and was of the opinion that MVVM was an overkill for his app.

Comment: You said "his app".So the case is not general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're on a tight schedule and have no knowledge of MVVM (or Prism?), then you'll be way better off using  options 3 and 1.  From my experience, it takes devs a long time to get up to speed on MVVM and Prism.  Certain things that are taken for granted, become much more difficult in the MVVM/Prism world.

With that being said, I'm a huge advocate of MVVM/Prism and feel that it's well worth the extra effort, especially for a project of your size.  However, since you're pressured for time, don't bother, just do code-behind.

Answer (score 1):

Prism takes time to learn, if you are on a tight deadline then I think you should just go with what you know, When you have time reading the prism book especially the section on navigation will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Don't go with PRISM,that would be an overkill for such non complex apps. If you are familiar with `DataBinding`, that can save you a lot of time even without MVVM.Since you're in a hurry, I think you should go with what you already know and start learning MVVM at ease.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

mvvm is not that hard. in your case you need first a mainviewmodel.

```
public class MainViewModel
{
   private ICollectionView _myView {get;set;}
   public ObservableCollection<MyModulWrapper> MyModules{get;set;}
   public MyModulWrapper SelectedModul {get;set;}

    public MainViewModel()
    {
       this.MyModules = new ObservableCollection<MyModulWrapper>();
       //i use icollectionview because i often need sorting or filtering
       this._myView = = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.MyModules);
       this._myView .CurrentChanged += (s, e) => { this.SelectedModul = this._myView .CurrentItem as MyModulWrapper; };
    }
}
```

you have to fill(in any way - i use mef for my apps, but hardcoded its also ok) your collection with all modules(viewmodels) you wanna show on your top screen.
the MyModulWrapper just contain the viewmodel for your modul and a nice display name for your navigation.

```
public class MyModulWrapper
{
   public string Displayname {get;set;}
   public object Modul {get;set;}//instead of object you can take an interface or base class or whatever
}
```

now you have all to let the mainview run :) you just have to set the datacontext for the MainWindow to your MainViewModel.

mainwindow.xaml

```
 <Window.Resources>
   <!--for each viewmodel you wanna show create a datatemplate. so wpf knows how to render your viewmodel-->
   <DataTemplate DataType={x:Type local:MyViewmodel4FirstButton>
     <local:MyFirstButtonView />
   </DataTemplate>
 </Window.Resources>

 <!-- for navigation -->
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyModules}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedModul , Mode=OneWay}"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Displayname}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>

  <!-- all you need to show your selected modul - if you have a DATATEMPLATEs!! -->
  <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedModul }"/>
```

all your viewmodels have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged of course, and raise it properly.

ps: code is written without IDE so ignore errors^^